# LoadRunner Correlation on application using Wickets (dynamic urls)

Tags: wicket, loadrunner

Loadtesting a wicket application with LoadRunner using WEB/HTTP protocol record and playback calls for challenges due to dynamic links. 
The same issue is relevant to other loadtesting frameworks as JMeter and this entry describes a solution for it using Regular Expression based approach:
`https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-and-jmeter-with-regular-expressions.html`
My concrete question is twofold:
The approach described using JMeter in the abovementioned link has a key point, namely to derive the URL that has to be used in the next step from the HTML respons for the previous step. In the JMeter example they use a Regular Expression Extractor to capture the respons to reuse it further down in the script.
Does this directly apply to a LoadRunner approach using manual correlation? 
My initial strategy to resolve issues I have with recording LoadRunner HTTP-protocol script for a wicket application is to get hold of the data needed to derive the URL thats has to be used in the next step. The example with JMeter uses Regular Expression Extractor.
Could this be directly related to web_reg_save_param in LoadRunner?

Comment: Consider a normal link of the form:
<a href="#" wicket:id="create">
The HTML generated at runtime will look something like this:
<a href="?wicket:interface=:4:create::ILinkListener:">
I want to grab the content of the "href" attribute using regular expression i LoadRunner. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe web_reg_save_param_regexp() could be used to do this capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web_reg_save_param() should be able to handle this easily. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I am not sure where to look in order to correlate this one. I assume it has to do With PagingNavigationIncrementLink(); some wicket "feature" incrementing the integer in the url in somewhat concecutive order. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I see exactly what you're trying to do. If I take your example from your comment:  <a href="?wicket:interface=:4:create::ILinkListener:"> then your left boundary would be '"LB=<a href=\""' and your right boundary will be '"RB=\">"'

Comment: I did fix this one. I used FireBug and fond some values in the response headers to correlate. However using URL mode and my script executing some JavaScript inside web_concurrent() the correlated value actually is changed after a web_reg_save_param_ex  and down to the scope where i put the value inside a web_url.

Comment: The above Challenge is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340396/loadrunner-correlation-phenomen